# Point specific page of website to a different server

Tags: web-hosting

I am a beginner. I want to point a specific page of my website say `example.com/xyz` to a different server.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is done using a proxy of some sort. This is NOT for beginners however. It is a huge security risk if not done right. My advice is to not attempt this.

Comment: What do you mean "point"? Please explain the scenario you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "Point" could mean "show content from a different server", or "redirect", or "link to."   Please edit your question to clarify.